# Tokyo cabinet - Slower inserts after hitting 1million

Tags: tokyo-cabinet

I am evaluating tokyo cabinet Table engine. The insert rate slows down considerable after hitting 1 million records. Batch size is 100,000 and is done within transaction. I tried setting the xmsiz but still no use. Has any one faced this problem with tokyo cabinet?

**Details**

> Tokyo cabinet - 1.4.3
>   Perl bindings - 1.23
>   OS : Ubuntu 7.10 (VMWare Player on top of Windows XP)

Answer (score 4):

I hit a brick wall around 1 million records per shard as well (sharding on the client side, nothing fancy). I tried various ttserver options and they seemed to make no difference, so I looked at the kernel side and found that

`echo 80 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio`

(previous value was 10) gave a big improvement - the following is the total size of the data (on 8 shards, each on its own node) printed every minute:

```
total:  14238792  records,  27.5881 GB size
total:  14263546  records,  27.6415 GB size
total:  14288997  records,  27.6824 GB size
total:  14309739  records,  27.7144 GB size
total:  14323563  records,  27.7438 GB size
(here I changed the dirty_ratio setting for all shards)
total:  14394007  records,  27.8996 GB size
total:  14486489  records,  28.0758 GB size
total:  14571409  records,  28.2898 GB size
total:  14663636  records,  28.4929 GB size
total:  14802109  records,  28.7366 GB size
```

So you can see that the improvement was in the order of 7-8 times. Database size was around 4.5GB per node at that point (including indexes) and the nodes have 8GB RAM (so dirty_ratio of 10 meant that the kernel tried to keep less than ca. 800MB dirty).

Next thing I'll try is ext2 (currently: ext3) and noatime and also keeping everything on a ramdisk (that would probably waste twice the amount of memory, but might be worth it).

Answer (score 2):

I just set the cache option and it is now significantly faster.

Answer (score 1):

I think modifying the bnum parameter in the dbtune function will also give a significant speed improvement.